# Showing specialization with UML

Tags: uml, entity-relationship, class-diagram

How do you show specialization in a UML diagram when two specialized entities could also be each other. For example:

```
    [Personel]
        ^
       /_\
        |
    ------------
    |           |   
[Employee]    [Manager]
```

Typically, I'd use the empty arrow to show specialization, but how do i show that an employee or manager could also have the other role in some instance? Do I just need to use a line to connect them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most common form Generalization is mutually exclusive. You are either one subclass or the other, but never the two at the same time.

For the example you used you better use the **Party-PartyRole** pattern.

[image]

`Employee` or `Manager` are **Roles** a person can play. With this pattern you can be both `Manager` and `Employee` at the same time.

Comment: I agree, although I would say that a particular instance of `PartyRole` is played by one `Party`. Also, the default in UML 2 is *overlapping*, not disjoint. Although your underlying model may have a generalization set that is {complete, disjoint}, one can't tell from this diagram.

Comment: @JimL. You are right, I fixed the error. I'm not sure about the `{complete, disjoint}` clause however. I did find `isDisjoint` as a parameter for a `GeneralizationSet`, but I couldn't find where the `complete` is coming from. But since a `Generalization` doesn't have to be part of a `GeneralizationSet` I should not specify that should I?

Comment: UML is a bit weird, in that the words shown in braces don't match the words in the metamodel. Table 9.1 in the UML 2.5 spec (formal-15-03-01) provides the mapping. The word `{complete}` maps to `isCovering=true`, the word `{incomplete}` maps to `isCovering=false`, the word `{disjoint}` maps to `isDisjoint=true`, and the word `{overlapping}` maps to `isDisjoint=false`. The default is `{incomplete, overlapping}`. I believe that default holds when generalizations are not in a generalization set.

Comment: I forgot to answer, "since a Generalization doesn't have to be part of a GeneralizationSet I should not specify that should I"? If you want readers to assume `{incomplete, overlapping}`, you don't need to specify. Since `PartyRole` is abstract, that implies an instance must be a `Manager` or `Employee` (or both, the way it's modeled). An abstract class implies `isCovering=true` / `{complete}`, which contradicts the default and has created a paradox in your model.